# Skip snakemake rules that depend on failed rule

Tags: python, snakemake

This is a section of my `snakemake` workflow:

[image]

The rule *bagel2bf* fails occasionally with certain data sets, but I do not want this to fail the entire `snakemake` run.

How can I adapt the workflow so that if there is an exit code 1 from rule *bagel2bf* it will skip the rules that are dependent on its output (maybe also printing a warning message)?

This is the code for the rules:

```
rule install_bagel2:
    output:
        directory("bagel2_software/"),
    shell:
        "git clone https://github.com/hart-lab/bagel.git {output}"
    

rule convert_count_table:
    input:
        "count/counts-aggregated.tsv"
    output:
        "count/counts-aggregated-bagel2.tsv"
    params:
        fa=fasta,
    resources:
        runtime=config["resources"]["stats"]["time"]
    conda:
        "envs/stats.yaml"
    script:
        "scripts/convert_count_table.py"


rule bagel2fc:
    input:
        "bagel2_software/",
        "count/counts-aggregated-bagel2.tsv",
    output:
        "bagel2/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.foldchange"
    resources:
        runtime=config["resources"]["stats"]["time"]
    conda:
        "envs/stats.yaml"
    log:
        "logs/bagel2/fc/{bcomparison}.log"
    script:
        "scripts/bagel2fc.py"


rule bagel2bf:
    input:
        "bagel2_software/",
        "bagel2/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.foldchange",
    output:
        "bagel2/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.bf"
    params:
        species=config["lib_info"][library]["species"],
    resources:
        runtime=config["resources"]["stats"]["time"]
    conda:
        "envs/stats.yaml"
    log:
        "logs/bagel2/bf_{bcomparison}.log"
    script:
        "scripts/bagel2bf.py"


rule bagel2pr:
    input:
        "bagel2_software/",
        "bagel2/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.bf",
    output:
        report("bagel2/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.pr", caption="report/bagel2.rst", category="BAGEL2")
    params:
        species=config["lib_info"][library]["species"]
    resources:
        runtime=config["resources"]["stats"]["time"]
    conda:
        "envs/stats.yaml"
    log:
        "logs/bagel2/pr_{bcomparison}.log"
    script:
        "scripts/bagel2pr.py"


rule plot_bf:
    input:
        "bagel2/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.bf"
    output:
        report("bagel2_plots/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.bf.pdf", caption="report/bagel2_plots.rst", category="BAGEL2 plots", subcategory="{bcomparison}", labels={"Comparison":"{bcomparison}", "Figure":"BF plot"})
    conda:
        "envs/stats.yaml"
    script:
        "scripts/plot_bf.py"


rule plot_pr:
    input:
        "bagel2/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.pr"
    output:
        report("bagel2_plots/{bcomparison}/{bcomparison}.pr.pdf", caption="report/bagel2_plots.rst", category="BAGEL2 plots", subcategory="{bcomparison}", labels={"Comparison":"{bcomparison}", "Figure":"Precision-recall plot"})
    conda:
        "envs/stats.yaml"
    script:
        "scripts/plot_pr.py"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would catch the exception in rule `bagel2bf`, e.g with python `try/except` or similar mechanism. Then write out the expected files with either nothing in them or with some useful, parsable information about the exception. Downstream rules will handle such files in a similar way by writing empty output files or some flag files.

I'm not aware of a mechanism to explicitly tell snakemake to skip part of the pipeline if something fails and I think this would be counter to snakemake's principles. I think the above solution is sensible because if failures are somewhat expected then downstream rules should handle them accordingly rather than skipping them.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [`--keep-going`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#all-options) flag.  With this, all downstream jobs of failed jobs won't run but any job that can be run will continue.  Once all jobs are exhausted the workflow run will fail and you'll have to fix failed jobs before starting again.  This is handy for the "last run of the night" where you want to make some progress and ignore jobs that will likely fail.